# sum columns in mysql from up to down rows and select the rows in which the value falls

Tags: mysql

lets say i have these type of data in db table. how can i perform query like when i pass some value it should sum from up to down rows and select the all rows which are required to sum up the value. 
1. when i pass value 11 it should sum from up to down rows and sum rows with id 1 2 3 i.e (3+2+7) as 11 falls in third row range and select all rows that equals or have greater) the value.

2.lets say if i pass 20 value it should sum row 1 2 3 4 as 20 falls in (3+2+7+10) 4th column and select all 4 rows.

```
ID, TABLE_COLUMN
1,2
2,3
3,7
4,10
5,11
6,15
```

please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach uses a correlated subquery which checks the rolling sum:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.TABLE_COLUMN
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(t2.TABLE_COLUMN), 0)
       FROM yourTable t2
       WHERE t2.ID < t1.ID) < 20;
```

### Demo

Comment: thanks Tim but i guess this will not work. as condition where ......... < 20 will results only 1 2 and 3  row i.e (3+2+7) as it sums up to 12. 4th row will not work as it has value greater then 20 i.e 22.i need to select the 4th row too :)